# Pokemon GO game experience would not recover after reset

Tags: pokemon-go

I had played Pokemon GO up to level 23.  Then after my phone was reset, the game went all the way back to the beginning.  I have tried the resets, reboots, sign in and sign outs multiple times.  It still went back to level one.  On the last attempt, the level 1 screen was not even functional--it only showed the avatar standing in an empty place, no pokestops, gyms or even roads or other landmarks were visible, and when I walked, the avatar just stood in one spot.  The game was not even playable at level 1.

Comment: You most likely signed in a different account the first time. The savegames are kept on Niantic's servers, but you do need to use the same account for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is your phone rooted , because it doesn't have support for root. I think you should contact Niantic after all.